# Laravel Mail Attachment

Tags: php, laravel, email, attachment

How to add email attachment in laravel? And the download link on that,and also to validate just the PDF and size is no longer up to 2mb. Sorry im just a student that love to code. Please help me.

This is my controller code

```
public function store_applier(Request $request)
{   
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nama' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'kontak' => 'required',
        'kategori'=>'required',
        'posisi' => 'required',
        'alamat' => 'required',
    ]); 

    $tambah = new appliers(); //kita buat objek yang terhubung ke table JOBS
    $tambah->nama = $request['nama'];
    $tambah->email = $request['email'];
    $tambah->kontak = $request['kontak'];
    $tambah->kategori = $request['kategori'];
    $tambah->posisi = $request['posisi'];
    $tambah->alamat = $request['alamat'];


    $file = $request->file('upload_cv');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('upload_cv')->move("cv/", $fileName);
    $tambah->upload_cv = $fileName;
    $tambah->save();

    $email = DB::table('user')->where('email');

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', [
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'HP' => $request['kontak'],
        'nama' => $request['nama'], 
        'posisi' => $request['posisi'], 
        'CV' => $tambah->upload_cv = $fileName
    ], function ($message) use ($request, $tambah, $email) {

        $message->from('stevanajja@gmail.com', $request->posisi);   

        $message->to('stevantinusl47@gmail.com')
                ->subject('Lamaran Baru')
                ->cc('stevanlai@yahoo.com.sg')
                ->replyTo($request->email);

        $message->getSwiftMessage();

    });

    return redirect()->to('index'); 
}
```

and this is the view code

```
**<h1>Lamaran Baru</h1>

From : {{ $email }}

<br />

NO.HP : {{$HP}}

<br />

=========================

<br /><br />

Nama saya {{ $nama }},

<br /><br />

Saya ingin melamar pekerjaan di PT.Halcom dengan posisi sebagai 

<h2>{{$posisi}}</h2>

<br />

Berikut saya lampirkan CV saya

<br /><br /><br />

*Klik link dibawah untuk melihat CV

<br />

<a href="{!!URL::asset('../cv/{{$CV}}')!!}">KLIK</a>**
```

sorry for my bad to wasting ur time to answer the stupid question.. i am just student

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `attach` method in your message chain.

```
$message->to('stevantinusl47@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Lamaran Baru')
        ->cc('stevanlai@yahoo.com.sg')
        ->replyTo($request->email)
        ->attach('path_to_pdf_file', [
            'as' => 'your-desired-name.zip', 
            'mime' => 'application/pdf'
        ]);
```

For your path

```
<a href="{{ asset('path-to-your-pdf-in-public-directory') }}">KLIK</a>
```

Comment: in ->attach() , what should i fill??

Comment: your path to pdf file. see my answer

Comment: I do have a similar question and hope you don't mind supporting on that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012537/how-can-i-attach-file-coming-from-the-public-folder-to-mail

Comment: To get the path easierly, you can use `Storage::path('subfolder/file.pdf')`