# Inserting Images in Email Attachment in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, email-attachments, dompdf

I have created an app using Laravel and uploaded it to the live server (`shared hosting`). I have programmed it such that emails are sent to clients together with email attachments generated via `DOMPDF`. The problem is that I **receive a phishing error in Gmail inbox concerning the attachment**. When I **remove the image from the attachment** the error disappears. Seems like am not inserting the image properly in the blade file. Please assist me on how to add the image via the controller then parse it to the view (that is sent as an attachment)?

~ Regards

**PDF Controller that loads the PDF file**

```
class PDFController extends Controller
{
    //Loads the PDF document
    public function getPDF(){
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.customer', ['format' => 'A5-L']);
        return $pdf->stream('customer.pdf')->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
    }
}
```

**Email blade**

```
        <div class="logo pull-right">
            <?php $image_path = '/img/logo.png'; ?>
           <a href='#'> <img src="{{  public_path().$image_path }}" alt="logo"> </a>

        </div>
```

**PagesController that sends the email**

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.customer', $data);
        Mail::send('emails.feedback', $data, function($message) use ($data, $pdf){
            $message->from('info@*************');
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('Feedback');
             //Attach output from PDF doc, customer.pdf is the name of the file attached
            $message->attachData($pdf->output(),'customer.pdf');
        });
```

Comment: Image is as a part of email template or as a attachment? And you are using inbuilt laravel Mailer for mail?

Comment: @Nirali Image is embedded in the email attachment,, am using laravel Mail.. Not using any template

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel inbuilt mailer then, Follow below structure

Crete mail class using

```
php artisan make:mail MailFileName
```

MailFileName.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MailFileName extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
           $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('from_email' ,'Title')->view('emails.email_ blade_file')->with(['data' => $this->data])->subject($subject)->attach($this->data['attachment_url']);
    }
}
```

In view you are passing $data variable so you can use all this variable just like normal blade file.

```
View File - resource/views/emails/email_ blade_file.blade.php
```

In your controller where you want to call mail function add,

SomeController.php

use use App\Mail\MailFileName;

Inside function,

```
$data['subject'] = 'New message from';
$data['data'] = ['your data'];


 Mail::to($to_email)->send(new MailFileName($data));
```

Comment: I have edited my post and added the Controller that sends the email together with its attachment. Please check it out and show me how I can add the image in the controller and parse it to the view (attachment).

Comment: @Pweb check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38821155/6429700 .May be it will help you. Or implement your logic given in explanation in my answer