# How can I attach file coming from the public folder to Mail?

Tags: laravel

I want to send an email with a pdf attachment named "pre-qualification" and that is inside my public directory. How can I access that?

This is what I have in my store method:

```
Mail::send(new OfferEmailUser($request));
```

And the OfferEmailUser looks like this:

```
public $request;

public function __construct($request)
{
    //
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->to($request->email, $request->name);
    $this->subject('Email Notification on offer');
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.offeremailuser');
}
```

Comment: There is a chapter in the docs about mail attachments: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#attachments

Answer (score 4):

As jelhan mentioned in their comment, Laravel's [mail attachment docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#attachments) should help here, e.g.

```
return $this->view('emails.offeremailuser');
```

becomes

```
return $this->view('emails.offeremailuser')
            ->attach('/path/to/file');
```

You may also be wondering how to reference the path to your file in the public folder. Laravel has a [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-public-path) for this too. The final result may look something like:

```
return $this->view('emails.offeremailuser')
            ->attach(public_path('pre-qualification.pdf'));
```

Comment: appreciate that. The main problem I guess was in the helper function to access the public path. It works now. And if you do not mind explaining, what is the difference to what you sent compared to Gaurav Vaghela answer, which he adds an array?
I saw that in the documentation but there is no explanation for the difference.

Comment: The array basically gives you more control over how the attachment is processed and presented - the 'as' parameter allows you to override the file name and call it something else, and the 'mime' provides relevant services a hint at the mime-type of the file. If you are happy with the defaults then an array isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function __construct($request)
{
    //
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->to($request->email, $request->name);
    $this->subject('Email Notification on offer');
    $this->attach('path_to_pdf_file', array(
        'as' => 'pdf-report.zip', 
        'mime' => 'application/pdf')
    );
}
```